# unity 3d game which is control by an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, network-programming, connection

What i want to do is to create a 3d car game in which enemy car is coming from front and you are going against your enemy and your car can just go toward left or right now every thing will work on your computer/unity(server) which is control by your android app(client).
I have created it on unity by using RPC and both client and server are on unity but problem is i am using android studio to build an android app so how to connect that app with unity and start communication between them.

i have 2 buttons on clientside and serverside

Client (when clicked client is connected and clienrside screen is loaded)

Server (when clicked server is started and serverside screen is loaded)

On Clientside screen
when play button is clicked game is started on serverside and it is control by my client side which has two button left and right

my main Uimanager script is written below and image of my game are attached so please help me as i am stuck in this problem for about a week[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF0Cc.png).

```
UiManager Script using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class UiManager : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 public GameObject car;
 public CarController moveCar;
 public NetworkView nView;
 string level1;

 void Start () {
 nView = GetComponent<NetworkView>();

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
 ClientLeft();
 // networkView.RPC;
 }

public void Pause()
{
 if(Time.timeScale == 1)
 {
     Time.timeScale = 0;
 }
 else if(Time.timeScale == 0)
 {
     Time.timeScale = 1;
 }
 }
 string ip = "127.0.0.1" ;
 int portno = 25001;
 public void Server()
 {

     Network.InitializeServer(10, portno); 
     if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server)
     {
         Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
     }


  }



 public void Client()
 {
     Network.Connect(ip, portno);
 if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)
 {
     Application.LoadLevel("clientSide");
 }

 }
 void OnConnectedToServer()
 {
 Application.LoadLevel("clientSide");
 }
 public void ClientPaly()
 {
  if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)
 {
     nView.RPC("Play", RPCMode.Server);
 }
 }
 public void ClientLeft()
 {
 if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)
 {
     // nView.RPC("moveLeft", RPCMode.Server);
     moveCar.moveLeft();
 }
 }
 public void ClientRight()
 {
 if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)
 {
     nView.RPC("moveRight", RPCMode.Server);

 }
 }
[RPC]
public void Play()
{
 Application.LoadLevel("Level1");
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J38S0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add click listener to buttons and send message to gameObject in using

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("gameObjectName", "methodName", "Variable");
```

for example

```
client.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UiManager", "Client", "");
        }
    });

server.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UiManager", "Server", "");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Dear Sabish
what to do to connect my android app which is created in android studio to this game which is in unity 3d

Comment: you need to export google Development build from unity 3d and import to android studio and write above script.

Comment: thanks but how  to export google Development build from unity 3d and import to android studio basically i new in both i have done all this work by watching videos and by googling